# React Redux not updating component on URL change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

My `ImageGallery` component is not updating itself when my URL changes.

For example, when I click an item it routes me from `'/movies/12345'` to `'/movies/9999'`, but the component itself is not updating to show the images associated with `'/movies/9999'`. Instead it shows the images associated with `'/movies/12345'`.

Parent Component:

```
class Parent extends Component { 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchImages(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

 render(){
   ..
     <ImageGallery />
   ..
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchImages })(Parent);
```

ImageGallery Component:

```
class ImageGallery extends Component {
    render(){
      return this.props.images.map(img => {
           <img src={img.image_path}
      })
}
}
```

And then I tried wrapping my `connect` function with `withRouter` and used `componentWillReceiveProps`. But this doesn't work it complains

> Cannot read property id of Undefined

```
class Parent extends Component { 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchImages(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
      this.props.fetchImages(nextProps.params.id);
    }
  }

 render(){
   ..
     <ImageGallery />
   ..
  }
}

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchImages })(Parent)
);
```

App.js

```
  <div>
    <NavBar />
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
      <Route exact path='/movies/:id' component={Parent} />
    </Router>
  </div>
```

How do I get the `ImageGallery` to display the correct images? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add render to **Route**

When you change `/movies/12345` to `/movies/9999` component will not render so for that we are adding **key** to component

App.js

```
<div>
  <NavBar />
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
    <Route
      exact
      path='/movies/:id'
      render={({ match }) => <Parent key={match.params.id || ''} />} // Add render 
    />
  </Router>
</div>
```

Comment: For  more info on this solution:
https://medium.com/@migcoder/difference-between-render-and-component-prop-on-react-router-v4-368ca7fedbec

Answer (score 0):

Check if the store updates when you fetch new images in componentWillReceiveProps. Otherwise it seems fine. There might be something wrong with the reducer.